# Removing all data except

Tags: regex, notepad++

Sample data:

```
"107","34.813080","117.195.184.97","10.1.10.46","UDP","366","Source port: 3867  Destination port: 52000"
"110","34.832201","10.1.10.46","117.195.184.97","UDP","1022","Source port: 52000  Destination port: 3867"
"112","35.155310","10.1.10.46","117.195.184.97","UDP","974","Source port: 52000  Destination port: 3867"
```

From notepad++ how can I delete all the data except this:

```
117.195.184.97
10.1.10.46
10.1.10.46
```

And format it as such:

```
date:117.195.184.97-117.195.184.97
date:117.195.1xx.xxx-117.195.1xx.xxx
```

This would be extremely helpful with what I do, notepad++ already has a filter to remove duplicate lines, so once they are filtered away, i can easily remove the duplicates.

Comment: Basically I just want the line (all lines in the CSV) to go from ("107","34.813080","117.195.184.97","10.1.10.46","UDP","366","Source port: 3867 Destination port: 52000") to this: 117.195.184.97 (new line)

Comment: Your edit is quite correct, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If your lines have always the same format and the field you want is always the third, you can use this:

search: `^.*?",".*?","(.*?)".*`
replace: `date:$1-$1`

details:

```
^        # start of the line
.*?","   # all until the first ","
.*?","   # all until the second ","
(.*?)"   # capture in group 1 until the next "
.*       # all until the end of the line
```

Comment: I love you so much right now, that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to search for "non commas".  Here you go:
Search for:

`^.[^,]*,[^,]*,"([^,]*\.[^,]*\.[^,]*\.[^,]*)".*`

and replace with 

`$1`

-Ed